# How to create a build of webservice cilent for linux server?

Tags: java, jax-ws

I have created web service client on my local machine by referring wsdl file placed in C drive. (JAX-WS) The code is running well on my machine. But the production server is linux machine. Hence i want to create web service client by giving relative path. Can anyone help in this case?

Comment: Why is the wsdl file not packaged into the war?

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your WSDL in the project (hint: `src/main/resources/wsdl/`).
2. Use a tool such as Apache CXF to generate the client.
3. Build the project.
4. Distribute the built artifacts to various runtime environments - Windows/Linux/Solaris/Whatever.

Have a look at this example: http://qwerky-qwerky.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/programming-without-programming-1.html

Comment: I am using Netbeans IDE.